# ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c++, winapi, память

Есть функция:

```
static bool Read (HANDLE window, LPVOID adress, void* valuve)
{

        VirtualProtectEx(window, (LPVOID*)adress, sizeof(valuve), PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, NULL);
        return ReadProcessMemory(window, adress, (LPVOID*)valuve, sizeof(valuve), NULL);
}
```

из main вызываю её так:

```
int i = 0;
LPVOID adress = 0x00;
bool result = Read(window, adress, (int*)i);
while (result == false)
{
    //test = (DWORD*)adress;
    cout << adress << "  no/n " << fuck   << endl;
    adress = adress + 0x000001;
    result = Read(window, adress, (int*)i);

}
```

`GetLastError` возвращает 6, так же печален вызов функции. Пожалуйста, поправьте. Но главное - решить проблему с `GetLastError`.

Comment: Как корабль назовешь, так он и поплывет :)

Comment: Я уже от отчаянья так её назвал :D

Comment: 1)  6 - invalid handle. Проверяйте ваше window.  2) Память можно читать, только если её разрешено читать (про access_violation не забываем). Доступность блока памяти проверяем VirtualQueryEx. Про доступ к хандлу вам ниже написали. Память по адресу ноль - как правило не доступна.

Answer (score 3):

1. Строго говоря неверно - `ReadProcessMemory(window, adress, (LPVOID*)valuve, sizeof(valuve), NULL);` Мы читаем 8 байтов (размер указателя) и пишем их по адресу, куда указывает valuve. Вообще же мы можем прочитать сколько угодно байтов на самом деле, а возможно и буфер, куда читаем меньше 8 байтов...
2. Почему мы берем хендл на Window, когда нужен хендл на процесс?
3. не забываем про подсистему безопасности шиндовз. Для нашего процесса необходимо право `PROCESS_VM_READ`. Если его нет - необходимо его получить.

Comment: Я просто привёл не весь код, хендл window - это хендл на открытый процесс с полными правами доступа.

Comment: Я бы добавил ещё, нужно что б доступ к блоку был разрешён. Память с адресом 0 нельзя читать.